# Problems with application prefix in getRequestURI when using Tomcat behind Apache proxy

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, proxy, ajp

I have a problem with my Tomcat behind an Apache server. I set up the Apache to be used as an AJP proxy, and it seems to work, if I open the browser on the apache server, I get the output from the Tomcat server. I have a problem the request URI. I use it in the programm, unfortunately it does not give me the correct URI:

When I visit this page:

```
http://<apache-server>/test
```

The line

```
logger.entry(request.getRequestURL().toString() + " " + request.getRequestURI().toString());
```

returns in the logs:

```
http://<apache-server>/app/test /app/test
```

Instead of what I would need:

```
http://<apache-server>/test /test
```

The configuration on the apache-server is this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ProxyRequests     off
      ProxyPreserveHost on
      ProxyPass / ajp://<tomcat-server>:8009/pps/
      ProxyPassReverse / ajp:/<tomcat-server>:8009/app/
</VirtualHost>
```

The tomcat server has this in its server.xml:

```
<Connector port="8009" 
            enableLookups="false" 
            redirectPort="8443" 
            protocol="AJP/1.3" />
```

I found pages suggesting to deploy the app as ROOT in tomcat, but this seems very dirty...

Comment: Why would it be dirty to deploy it as ROOT, since you want it at root?

Comment: I do not want it as root on the tomcat server, only root on the remote apache server. The apache server maps this domain to the tomcat, but this will not be the only app. I will have another subdomain for another app on the same tomcat server which needs to work in the same way. Of course, I could run multiple tomcat instances, but this would be a huge waste of resources.